# Making a generic query / getbyspecification in web api controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a typical API with some CRUD operations. I typically need to get certain objects, based on different parameters.

One way to do it would be to have methods like:

```
GetProjectsByCustomerId(int customerId);
GetProjectsBySigneeId(int signeeId);
```

However, in my service layer (`ProjectService` in this case) I usually use a method such as the following where `ProjectSpecification` typically has quite a lot of fields and even lists:

```
public IEnumerable<Project> GetBySpecification(ProjectSpecification projectSpecification)
```

That means, in my dream world I would like to have endpoints such as:

- `/api/projects` (empty specification, return full list)
- `/api/projects?customerid=2` (gets projects for customer with id 2)
- `/api/projects?signeeid=2,3` (get projects with signee id 2 and 3)

**My question is - how is this done**

My first attempt was adding this in my `ProjectController` (calling my `ProjectService`):

```
public class ProjectsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects(ProjectSpecification projectSpecification)
    {
        var projects = _projectService.GetBySpecification(projectSpecification);
        return projects;
    }
}
```

But lets say I open this URL:

```
/api/Projects?CustomerId=2
```

This is not parsed into a `ProjectSpecification` viewmodel. However, if I change my controller signature to:

```
public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects(int customerid) { }
```

It would work, because it's a simple type.

I could of course build some parameter-hell, but I guess there is something super obvious MVC magic I am missing - probably in the routing? :-)

Comment: Show `ProjectSpecification` as part of the example. Also look into the `FromUri` attribute on the parameter

Comment: The `ProjectSpecification` class would work fine, but you may need to build a custom model binder (not hard at all). Alternatively you may want to look at OData which pretty much does this for you anyway.

Comment: @DavidG I think you're right that ODATA would probably be what I want, but for the purpose here lets stick with REST. What would be the simplest example of a custom modal binder here? (Thanks btw =) )

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding

Comment: For web api look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api . `[FromUri]` should be simple enough for this scenario.

Comment: FromURI worked. Thanks guys :-) Solved my problem! I'll also look into more advanced model binding !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing documentation

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API : [FromUri]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri)

> To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the
>   `[FromUri]` attribute to the parameter.

For example assuming

```
public class ProjectSpecification {
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    //...other properties
}

public class ProjectsController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActinoResult GetProjects([FromUri]ProjectSpecification projectSpecification) {
        return Ok(projectSpecification);
    }
}
```

The client can put the `CustomerId` value in the query string.

For example:

```
/api/Projects?CustomerId=2
```

and Web API will use them to construct a `ProjectSpecification` with the `CustomerId` set to `2` .